# Wordpress Plug-In for Documents Library

Tags: wordpress, plugins, documents

I need a very easy to use plug-in which will help me have this effect in Wordpress. Please note that simple page editing is not working -- add text and set hyperlink (this is not working). We need PDF & PPT files for now, however if there is a solution with wider variety of file type it would be great.

Please see the below reference hyperlink for more visual explanation - TAB "Manuals" (I do not need the tabs, justthe list):-

http://support.lexmark.com/index?segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en&productCode=LEXMARK_C524&page=product&frompage=null#5

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/document-library/